# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNCSafeAreaViewConfig.Constants')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNCSafeAreaViewConfig.Constants')

<global>
    InitialWindowSafeAreaInsets.ts:9:38
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    index.tsx:6
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    StackView.js:1:763
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    index.js:1:413
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    index.js:1
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    AppNavigator.js:2
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    App.js:14
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    index.js:3
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:201:45
global code
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:178228:4
```

Hi, I am facing this issue while creating my app in iOS don't know where i am doing wrong please help me out. This error might be from react-native-safe-area-view. I have also installed it but still getting this error. Thanks

Comment: Can you add related code please?

Comment: Which code you need ? Above screen i am getting while building the app

Comment: @WarVic try this in your terminal `> cd ios` `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

add this to your ios/Podfile:

`pod 'react-native-safe-area-context', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context'`

then run `pod install`